# VS2017 indenting on braces in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I have watched several `C++` tutorials on `Pluralsight` using `VS2017` and whenever the author types a pair of braces and presses enter, the cursor always appears indented and on the middle line, ready for typing to commence (see `image 2`).  In my `VS2017` however, the cursor always appears in front of the closing brace (see `image 1`), so I have to press enter to create a blank line between the braces, move the cursor up and then type a tab before I can start typing.

I have searched the settings in `VS2017` under `text editor/C++` but cannot find how to change this behaviour.  It's annoying and I'm thinking there must be a way to change it.

Does anyone know how please?

[image: Braces]

Comment: What happens if you type just `{` and Enter?

Comment: RustyX, in that case there is no change; I still get the problematic behaviour.  Joe's answer below was the solution.

Comment: Also, why the downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tools >> Options >> Text Editor >> C++ >> Formatting >> General

Be sure that "Automatically format braces when they are automatically completed" is checked.

That should give you what you want